# Minimum number of adjustments to make array elements equal or 0

Tags: algorithm, adhoc

Suppose we have an array of fixed length *N* containing non-negative integers. Our aim is to make the array evenly distributed in a special way. After our operations every non zero elements in the array should be equal. The only operation we can perform is : subtract 1 from an element and add 1 to any other element. I am interested to know the minimum number of such operations needed.

Formally,

```
 final_arr[i] = 0 or k
 for all i in [1,N]
 k maybe any positive integer
```

Example,

```
 1.
 arr = [5,2,3,0,0,0]
 operation 1 : (2-1),(3+1)   arr = [5,1,4,0,0,0]
 operation 2 : (1-1),(4+1)   final_arr = [5,0,5,0,0,0]
 so minimum number of operations is 2 (here k = 5)

 2.
 arr = [5,2,1,0,0,0]
 operation 1 : (2-1),(5+1)   arr = [6,1,1,0,0,0]
 operation 2 : (1-1),(6+1)   arr = [7,0,1,0,0,0]
 operation 3 : (1-1),(7+1)   final_arr = [8,0,0,0,0,0]
 so minimum number of operations is 3 (here k = 8)
```

Note : N<=20 and arr[i]<=10^8

I'm aware of the fact that a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491848/how-to-find-the-minimum-number-of-operations-to-make-the-string-balanced) exists but this question is more generalized and currently that question is locked.

Comment: Hint: what would be the best "target value" of the array?

Comment: target value should be a number which will give the sum of all elements when multiplied with the number of non-zero elements (in the final array). But how to find the number of non zero elements in the optimal solution? Can you provide some more hint?

Comment: The number of non-zero elements is <=N, and N<=20, and it has to be a factor of the total sum.  Each possibility implies a specific target value.  Just try them all -- this question is about how to minimize the cost of trying each one.  You can do this in O(N) time.

Comment: This problem is basiclly the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491848 , it's just expressed in a different way. Oh, actually it's a bit simpler (it's the 2nd half of the problem). And, the link already contains the algorithm (by others), and implemention (by me).

Comment: @EricWang can you please explain the reduction? The question you pointed to does not require that each change in one element correspond with a change in another.

Comment: @MattTimmermans how can it be done in O(n)? I don't  see it.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Ah, that might be a mistake.  I thought I had a way to avoid sorting the array, but it didn't pan out when I tried to explain it to you.  I'm going to think about it for a while to see if it's recoverable.

Comment: @גלעדברקן In the question I mention, if a char is removed, then must add another char, so that is the same as when reduce a number by 1, must increase another number by 1. So, they are the same, isn't it?

Comment: @EricWang  I don't think so. That question says: "You may perform the following operation any number of times (including zero): Choose one letter in S and replace it by another uppercase English letter." I think we should reopen this question.

Comment: @גלעדברקן The sum of array elements never changes, that makes the 2 questions identical. So, I really didn't get what's their difference? Adding to 0 is like introduce a new char not existing in original string, adding to non-zero is to increasing an existing char in original string.

Comment: @EricWang cool, I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: The fact is that I found the problem from the same website https://www.codechef.com as the op mentioned in that question.That question is directly copied from the source but I translated and generalized the question a bit. That question is currently locked. I think duplicate tag may be removed to allow someone to provide a different solution for this question.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I further refactored my code in the other question, the frequency table is created in an individual function now, you can try to run the test case locally, there are a lot comments there, it should be easier to read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54495045

Comment: @SujanDutta ... they said you accepted this as a duplicate. Did you not? So I told them to cancel my reopen request. (See here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). If you'd like it reopened, you may need to ask again or post another question.

Comment: Yes I accepted that this is a duplicate. But at that time the other question was not looked.

Comment: @SujanDutta: Why do you mind that that question is locked? If it answers your question, then it answers your question. No?